# Search API get team and communication sites

Tags: sharepoint-online, search, sharepoint-rest-api, search-api

How do I search for Team Sites and Communication Sites using SharePoint Search REST API?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use the below endpoint:

```
/_api/search/query?querytext='contentclass:sts_site webtemplate=SITEPAGEPUBLISHING 
webtemplate=GROUP'&rowlimit=500
```

The base template value of Communication site is `SITEPAGEPUBLISHING` and that of modern team site backed by O365 group is `GROUP`.

Reference - [List all communication sites in SPO](https://www.techmikael.com/2017/08/how-to-list-all-communication-sites-in.html)

[Get list of all O365 group sites](https://www.aerieconsulting.com/blog/how-to-get-list-of-sites-created-by-office365-groups)

**Note** - at the moment, private groups are not visible via search even if you are a member of the group.

Comment: Nice. You were faster ;)